# Lightweight portable C++ threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, portability

Does anyone know about a lightweight portable C++ threading library, that can work on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X?

Specifically in my case, I do a simulator that after each time passes exports simulated data. I would like to run only one thread (simulate) that would once in a while start another thread (export). The only condition would be: if export thread started wait until it finishes, before starting a new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about [TinyThread++](http://tinythread.sourceforge.net/)?

> Need portable threads for your C++
>   app? Is C++0x unavailable for your
>   target compiler(s)? Is Boost too
>   large?
>
> Then you need TinyThread++!
>
> TinyThread++ implements a fairly
>   compatible subset of the C++0x thread
>   management classes.

Answer (score 12):

I use [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) and would recommend it to others.

It is portable to almost everything and easy to use.  The "lightweight" thing is the only question, since I am not really sure what that means.  Boost is lightweight in that there is almost no overhead to using it, since all the threading functionality is loose static wrapping for the underlying threading library (`pthreads`, Win32 API, Cell BE, etc).  A "mutex" is really anything that implements that "Lockable" concept (see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts)), which can be anything - even your own special whatever.  In that sense, it is very lightweight and extensible.

*However*, Boost is a *huge* library and pulling just the parts of it you need can be extremely painful (this is a common complaint about Boost in general).  Off the top of my head, using Boost.Thread means you have to have Boost.DateTime, Boost.System, Boost.ConceptCheck and Boost.Compiler (and probably more and whatever those rely on, etc).  To their credit, it is very easy to build what you need if you have the whole library due to their automatic linking magic, but the need to have it all is definitely something to consider, especially if Windows is on the list of targets.

As an alternative to Boost, I would recommend [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), assuming your compiler has support for it.  The fact that it requires compiler support for some of the more advanced features might disqualify it on the "lightweight" thing, but it is pretty lightweight on usage (the first time you `#pragma omp parallel for` is pretty neat).  It is not as feature-packed as Boost (I think only Qt can compete here), but using OpenMP gives you some really cool features that no other threading library can do.  You'll have to use a somewhat modern compiler, but both GCC and MSVC have good support here.  One caveat is that it is really a C library, which I see as a disadvantage if you're doing C++, but that could be a good thing for your requirements.

If you're looking for something significantly more lightweight (in both senses of the word), then I would recommend [OpenThreads](http://openthreads.sourceforge.net/).  It is nowhere near as extensible as Boost and find it less performant (not significantly, though), it is pretty well-designed and worth mentioning.  It will hit all of your specified targets (Windows, OSX and Linux), so if it has the features you want, go for it.

Also, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C%2B%2B_multi-threading_libraries).

Comment: It is hardly lightweight. Even a `bcp thread` command to select just the thread library from boost will give you 9 megabytes of source code.

Comment: @noxmetus: It depends what the word "lightweight" means.

Comment: @Travis Gockel: The Oxford Dictionary gives the following general meaning of this word: “of thin material or build and weighing _less than average_”. 9 megabytes of source code that includes besides the thread library itself a dozen of different unrelated libraries is definitely more than average. pthreads for Windows, for example is just 1.9 megabytes.

Comment: @noxmetus: But the "weight" of the source code isn't what I care about.  I care about usage overhead, which Boost has basically none.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Travis Gockel: Why what you do or do not care about should matter for the topic starter? It is a rhetorical question. The lack of the usage overhead is not true either. First of all one will need to figure out how to compile bjam and bcp. Then `boost::thread` library requires compilation as well. Which will require in turn basic understanding of boost build system and how to tune it to correspond to one's project settings `boost::thread` is going to be used with.

Comment: @noxmetus: Because the topic starter did not specify the meaning of "lightweight," I had to guess.  And I meant run-time usage overhead.  Any external library you use is going to need to go through compilation, understanding the system and tuning build settings...so Boost really isn't that different in that regard.

Comment: @Travis Gockel: Any source code needs to be compiled, yes. In some cases you just need to include a header file. Sometimes add a file to your project, or even run a make. But boost is extremely different in this regard. Boost uses the unique building system in contrast to other libraries. To use it properly you have to know what is bjam, how to build and run it, what is user-config.jam, sometimes add something like `modules.poke common` there, etc... I am fine with it, but it just hardly fits “none of usage overhead” definition.

Answer (score 2):

[Boot.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) is what you are looking for. To quote its description in Boost's doc pages

> Portable C++ multi-threading.

Comment: Lightweight ? Why ignoring this requirement ?

Comment: @Matthieu M. To quote @Travis Gockel "It depends what the word 'lightweight' means"

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread.html) would work here.

You can use [join](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.join) to wait for an existing thread to finish.

There are other code samples in the docs but starting a thread looks like this:

```
struct callable
{
    void operator()();
};

boost::thread copies_are_safe()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(x);
} // x is destroyed, but the newly-created thread has a copy, so this is OK

boost::thread oops()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(boost::ref(x));
} // x is destroyed, but the newly-created thread still has a reference
  // this leads to undefined behaviour
```

Answer (score 0):

I've mostly heard about Boost.Thread which can be pretty heavy, Poco.Thread which is supposed to be lightweight and Intel's TBB which I don't know how it works.

I did a little experimentation with C++0x but I've been told it's not mature enough yet for complex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I use the c++11 Standar for threads to create a  class multithreading and it works for Linux, Windows and OS X, may it be could be use full for you:

https://github.com/jorgemedra/C-11-Threads/blob/master/README.md